# Wrong text alignment in row using QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, text-alignment, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` (with `PyQt4`) with custom and resized icons using the code below, but the **Size** column is displaying a wrong alignment/position, like so:

[image]

```
        self.ui.treeView.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30,30))

        fileSystemModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel(self.ui.treeView)
        custonIconProvider = CustomIconsProvider()
        fileSystemModel.setIconProvider(custonIconProvider)

        self.ui.treeView.setModel(fileSystemModel)
        self.ui.treeView.setRootIndex(fileSystemModel.setRootPath(forlderPath))

        self.ui.treeView.setColumnWidth(0, 250)
        self.ui.treeView.setColumnWidth(1, 70)
        self.ui.treeView.setColumnWidth(2, 70)
```

I've searched the http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreeview.html documentation for a possible fix, but couldn't find anything evident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to fix this is to reimplement the model's [data() method](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html#data) so that the value for the TextAlignmentRole always includes the AlignVCenter flag:

```
# python3 or sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

class FileSystemModel(QtGui.QFileSystemModel):
    def data(self, index, role):
        value = super(FileSystemModel, self).data(index, role)
        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole and value is not None:
            value |= QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
        return value
```

```
# python2 or sip.setapi('QVariant', 1)

class FileSystemModel(QtGui.QFileSystemModel):
    def data(self, index, role):
        value = super(FileSystemModel, self).data(index, role)
        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole and value.isValid():
            value = value.toInt()[0] | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
        return value
```

Comment: Hey ekhumoro, thanks a lot for revisiting this post! It's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

view -> model -> setData( **index**, YOUR_VALUE, Qt::TextAlignmentRole )

Comment: I don't know python, but I specified methods that should be called. I think that it is clear, what to do. If someone downvoted - please, add comments, why.

Comment: I didn't down voted your answer, it was someone else. I understood your code and tried it in Python, but I didn't get the desired effect.

Comment: I tried this code: fileSystemModel.setData(QtCore.QModelIndex(), QtCore.QVariant(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft),
              QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole)

Comment: You are passing invalid `QModelIndex`. You should path valid index for each cell. Or it is better to subclass your model and reimplement `data` method, that will always return prefferable value for "size" column.

Comment: Maybe I'll have to call it in a loop for each item, like this links suggests: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-595

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that my QtCore.QModelIndex() call was wrong from the start.

Comment: Loop is not good solution, because you should somehow track model for modifications and set alignment for each new items. Much better to subclass model ;)

Comment: I'll try to subclass it. Thanks for your thoughts and time!

Comment: No problem. Btw, there are special buttons/arrows for "thanks" ;)

Comment: Here http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfilesystemmodel.html doesn't say that the class QFileSystemModel has a TextAlignmentRole.

Comment: It's a not class property. It's attribute of ANY item. It's located in global Qt namespace.